# jQuery : AJAX Load Content No Page Refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load content without reloading the whole page with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('article').load('content/index.php');

 $('a.cta , a').click(function()  {
       var page = $(this).attr('href');

      $('article').load('content/' + page + '.php');
      return false;
   });
});
```

For the most part its working fine as [seen here:](http://visual-grace-website-design.com/house2home_AJAX/)

The only problem I'm getting is that the links withing my content area aren't working but every other link outside my content area is. Why is that? What am I missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delegated events (`on()` function).

```
$('article').load('content/index.php', function () {
   $("article").on("click", 'a.cta , a', function()  {
      var page = $(this).attr('href');

      $('article').load('content/' + page + '.php');
      return false;
   });   
});
```

[**See the documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more information.

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Answer (score 0):

that is beacuse you need to delegate the dynamically added element with `on`. `click` events won't work for dynamically added elements..

try this

```
$(document).on('click','a.cta , a',function()  {
   var page = $(this).attr('href');

  $('article').load('content/' + page + '.php');
  return false;
 });
});
```

delegating it to the closest static parent is recommended for better performance.

```
$(article).on('click','a.cta , a',function()  {
```

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about `on` delegated event

Answer (score 0):

It's because those `a`s within the `article` element are dynamic. The click event was never bound to those. Instead, use event delegation:

```
$('article').on('click', 'a.cta, a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //better than return false
    var page = $(this).attr('href');

    $('article').load('content/' + page + '.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('article').load('content/index.php', function () {

$(document).on('click','a.cta , a',function()  {
   var page = $(this).attr('href');

  $('article').load('content/' + page + '.php');
  return false;
    });
  });
});
```

It's really frustrating when you barely know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

try commenting out the line `return false;` and all the links will work.

so...

```
return false;
```

change to...

```
//return false;
```